# Google Cloud ML - Can't find module

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run a model on Google Cloud ML, but I'm having trouble even to to run it locally

I have my code organized like this :

```
cloud/
  trainer/
        task.py
        othermodules.py
```

I have a module that import other modules.

Following the guides on how to run the model first locally, they give the next command:

```
gcloud ml-engine local train 
--package-path trainer/ 
--module-name trainer.task
--job-dir=$MODEL
```

I run this command, while I'm inside the folder called **cloud** but I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named adressing
```

Where adressing is one of the modules in the **trainer folder** and the file adressing.py is in fact in the folder.

But if I run it using, **python trainer/task.py**  it works perfectly.

Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: Are you perhaps missing an empty `__init__.py` file in the trainer directory? That is used to package your code: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/packaging-trainer#building_your_trainer_package_manually

Comment: HI! i have the __init__.py but it still doesn't work... i'm running out of ideas with this one :/

Comment: i fix it. in some of the files, was an import from future absolute_import and by removing this, the code work.

Comment: Please formulate the finale solution as an answer to your question. Be as specific as possible and then accept your own answer.